# Date Formatting when creating a Model

Tags: sapui5

I'm hard-coding some dates to write back to a model.

E.g.

```js
oEntry.StartDate = "2016-03-28T00:00:00";
```

This is throwing out an invalid date error on:

```js
oModel.create("/CalendarSet", oEntry, {
  success : success,
  error : error
});
```

What is the correct format for the date?

Comment: have a look at that URL: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3423205

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the Javascript Date element.

```js
oEntry = {
    StartDate: new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
};

oModel.create("/CalendarSet", oEntry, {
    success : success,
    error : error
});
```

Source:[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

If you need it for the sPath in the URL you can use following to get a DateTime String.

```js
    getTimestamp: function getTimestamp(oDate){ //TODO: JsDoc
        this.oLogger.info("Enterd function  Timestamp(oDate)");
        return sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance({pattern : "yyyy-MM-ddTKK:mm:ss"}).format(oDate || new Date());
    },
```

Comment: Please use MDN instead.

Answer (score -1):

This is what you need:

```js
oEntry = {};
oEntry.StartDate = new Date(); // assuming "StartDate" is corr. fieldname in your service
                               // also assuming its the only key in your entity 
                               // and its type DateTime
oModel.create("/CalendarSet", oEntry, {
    success : success,
    error : error
});
```